# Solving coupled integral equations

Tags: numerical-methods, matlab, integral-equations, mathematica

I would like to solve coupled integral equations of following form:
$$
\begin{cases}
f(0,n) = 1 + \displaystyle\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}  K(n,p)f(1,p)dp \\
f(1,n) = g(n) + \displaystyle\int\limits_{0}^{\infty} \kappa(0,p)f(0,p)dp
\end{cases}
$$
where, $K(n,p)$ and $\kappa(n,p)$ are kernels. Also $f(0,n)$ and $f(1,n)$ are known to reach asymptotically equal values as $n\to\infty$.
It would be helpful if you direct me to appropriate numerical method for such kind of equations that I can easily implement in MATLAB/Mathematica.

Comment: Thanks Daniele, for the suggested edits. Any idea on how to solve this problem ?